# vue-suggestions dadata не получается присвоить значение переменной

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Пытаюсь использовать плагин vue-suggestions для dadata.ru, все находится, вставляется, но как присвоить значения оттуда переменной test ума не приложу. Если в методе onSelect() вставлять this.test, то он не понимает что это. Стрелочная функция там не работает. Как присвоить переменной test полученное значение?

```
  export default {
        data() {
            return {
                test: {},
                city: '',
                coordinates: {
                    latitude: '',
                    longitude: ''
                },
                suggestionOptions: {
                    // @see https://confluence.hflabs.ru/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=207454318
                    token: 'rtjsrtjsrj54u4j',
                    type: "ADDRESS",
                    scrollOnFocus: false,
                    triggerSelectOnBlur: false,
                    triggerSelectOnEnter: true,
                    addon: 'none',
                    // @see https://confluence.hflabs.ru/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=207454320
                    onSelect(suggestion) {
                        console.log(suggestion);
                    }
                },
             }
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если нельзя перебивать `this` в методе `onSelect`, можно вынести объект `data` в константу и ссылаться на нее

```
export default {
    data() {
        const data = {
            test: {},
            city: '',
            coordinates: {
                latitude: '',
                longitude: ''
            },
            suggestionOptions: {
                // @see https://confluence.hflabs.ru/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=207454318
                token: 'rtjsrtjsrj54u4j',
                type: "ADDRESS",
                scrollOnFocus: false,
                triggerSelectOnBlur: false,
                triggerSelectOnEnter: true,
                addon: 'none',
                // @see https://confluence.hflabs.ru/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=207454320
                onSelect(suggestion) {
                    data.test = suggestion
                }
            }
         };
         return data
     }
}
```

или так

```
export default {
    data() {
        const data = this;
        return {
            test: {},
            city: '',
            coordinates: {
                latitude: '',
                longitude: ''
            },
            suggestionOptions: {
                // @see https://confluence.hflabs.ru/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=207454318
                token: 'rtjsrtjsrj54u4j',
                type: "ADDRESS",
                scrollOnFocus: false,
                triggerSelectOnBlur: false,
                triggerSelectOnEnter: true,
                addon: 'none',
                // @see https://confluence.hflabs.ru/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=207454320
                onSelect(suggestion) {
                    data.test = suggestion
                }
            }
         }
     }
}
```